# How to pass results from one query to another in Robo3T

Tags: arrays, mongodb, function, object, robo3t

I'm trying to pass the results from one MongoDB query to another but the results are in Object and I need it as an Array.
Example:

```
var locId = db.getCollection('locations').find({country:"France"}, {_id:1}).toArray()
```

How can I pass the results to another query:

```
db.getCollection('products').find({locId: {$in: locId }})
```

The results from the first query are something like:

```
array[1] [
obj[0] {_id: LocId123},
obj[1] {_id: LocId456},
obj[1] {_id: LocId789},
]
```

I was able to pass the values with this:

```
locId = Array.from(locId , value => value._id )
```

The problem is that I cannot encapsulate this in an external function because I cannot pass this "_id" by the function parameters.
Any ideas on how to automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to combine all ids in a array,

- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) `country` condition
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `null` means none and push `_id` in array `ids`
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to show `_ids` and hide `_id`

```
var locId = db.getCollection('locations').aggregate([
  { $match: { country: "france" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ids: { $push: "$_id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, ids: 1 }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8_uzjCNMy00

Result:

```
[{
    "ids": [1, 2, 3]
}]
```

You Can Access:

```
db.getCollection('products').find({locId: {$in: locId[0]['ids'] }})
```

---

If you want to combine both query in single aggregation query then try,

- `$match` `country` condition
- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to join `products` collection using localField `_id` to foreignField `locId`
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to deconstruct `products` array
- `$group` by `_id` null and push all products in `products`
- `$unwind` to deconstruct `products` array
- `$project` to show required fields

```
var products = db.getCollection('locations').aggregate([
  {
    $match: { country: "france" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      as: "products",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "locId"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      products: { $push: "$products" }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$products._id",
      locId: "$products.locId"
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xOnohm0OWBV

Comment: can you console `locId` are you getting result?

Comment: Yes, the console log is fine. It returns 1 array inside 1 object inside 1 array of 5 elements

Comment: I don't know how to attach a screenshot here. I think the issue is coming from this locId[0]['ids']

Comment: No, this locId[0][0]['ids'] also is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219545/discussion-between-turivishal-and-ivo-hristov).

Comment: I was able to run it like this var locId = locId._batch